# I am facing the MUI select styling prob

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

```
<FormControl>
<Select
      labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={1}
        className={styles.customSelectRoot}
        IconComponent={() => <MyCustomIcon />}
        sx={{
          ".MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline": { border: 0},
          paddingLeft: "10px",
          paddingRight: "10px",
        }}
      >
        <MenuItem value={1}>Monthly</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={2}>Yearly</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={3}>Days</MenuItem>
      </Select>
</FormControl>
```

how to remove the paddingRight from default text showed in Select(mui component) Btn
its default 32px
and i am not able to change it

I tried this
"+ .MuiSelect-root .MuiSelect-select:focus": {
padding: 0,
},
but nothing happened

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it from `SelectDisplayProps`

```
<FormControl>
    <Select
      // other props
      SelectDisplayProps={{
        style: { 
          paddingLeft: "10px",
          paddingRight: "10px" 
        },
      }}
    >
      Your content
    </Select>
  </FormControl>
```